# python-using comma's when implementing before animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

i saw the wonderful example of the double_pendulum in order to start using the matplotlib animation.
this is a part of the code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal',autoscale_on=True)
ax.grid()

line, = ax.plot([], [], 'b-', lw=2)
time_text = ax.text(0.02, 0.95, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
energy_text = ax.text(0.02, 0.90, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

and i wanted to ask why did he use the comma when implementing the ax.plot into line. 
when i used a similar code, i also needed to use line, as a return statement for the init function even though it was the only object returned. i tried to look a bit and couldn't find an answer. can someone help me get the hang of it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ax.plot` returns a **list** of the lines added to the plot. Since you only add one line, `ax.plot` returns a list containing one line. `line, =` uses the Python unpacking syntax to pull that single line out of the list. It is equivalent to writing

```
line = ax.plot(...)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`ax.plot([], [], 'b-', lw=2)` returns a 1-element list in this case, which is unpacked upon assignment. Without the comma

```
line = x.plot([], [], 'b-', lw=2)
```

`line` would be the list instead of the single element of that list.

It's basically analog to this:

```
a, b = (1, 2)
```

where `a` is assigned 1 and `b` is assigned 2.